Cross join is taken to much time to execute in clickhouse

The calldetails table is receiving live data.
a view was constructed that would accept any data that is added to calldetails and use those records.
Our view generates 30-minute time segments for that day using those records. For instance, 00:00:00 - 00:29:00, 00:30:00 - 00:59:00, and so on, all the way up to 23:30:00 - 23:59:00
At that point, whatever data exists is added to those time slots.
compute positive, negative, and neutral sentiments from there.

CREATE VIEW IC_Campaign_half_an_hour_campaigntest AS;
show create table call_details_testt ;

WITH max_date AS (
  SELECT max(StartTime) AS latest_date
  FROM voc.call_details_testt cd
)
,time_intervals AS (
  SELECT 
    addMinutes(toStartOfDay(latest_date), n.number * 30) AS StartTime,
    addMinutes(toStartOfDay(latest_date), (n.number + 1) * 30) AS EndTime,
    latest_date
  FROM numbers(48) AS n
  CROSS JOIN max_date
)
 ,sentiment_counts AS (
  SELECT 
    ti.StartTime,
    ti.EndTime,
    cd.CampaignName,
    countIf(cd.sentiment = 'positive') AS PositiveCount,
    countIf(cd.sentiment = 'negative') AS NegativeCount,
    countIf(cd.sentiment = 'neutral') AS NeutralCount,
    COUNT(cd.sentiment) as Total_calls
    ,ti.latest_date
  FROM time_intervals ti
  CROSS JOIN voc.call_details_testt cd
  WHERE cd.StartTime >= ti.StartTime AND cd.StartTime < ti.EndTime
  GROUP BY 
    ti.StartTime, ti.EndTime, cd.CampaignName, ti.latest_date
)
SELECT 
  sc.StartTime,
  sc.EndTime,
  sc.CampaignName,
  sc.Total_calls,
  sc.PositiveCount,
  round((sc.PositiveCount / sc.Total_calls) * 100, 2) as Positive_percentage,
  sc.NegativeCount,
  round((sc.NegativeCount / sc.Total_calls) * 100, 2) as Negative_percentage,
  sc.NeutralCount,
  round((sc.NeutralCount / sc.Total_calls) * 100, 2) as Neutral_percentage
FROM sentiment_counts AS sc
WHERE sc.StartTime >= toStartOfDay(sc.latest_date)
  AND sc.StartTime < addDays(toStartOfDay(sc.latest_date), 1)
ORDER BY sc.StartTime, sc.CampaignName;


In sentiment_counts I used cross join, now for the large data set it will take too much time.
tired multiple approaches like join on (sc.StartTime >= toStartOfDay(sc.latest_date) AND sc.StartTime < addDays(toStartOfDay(sc.latest_date), 1)) and union all. but none of them are working

